# Maven dependencies conflict selenium-firefox-driver vs tint-runner

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

So I am working on this project where these two dependencies selenium-firefox-driver and tint-runner are needed. Well the problem is that tint-runner indirectly depends on guava-19 but selenium-firefox-driver depends on guava-25.
So what i can do? I tried to change the pom dependency order and also tried to add guava-25 as a direct dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be just one guava. You need to decide if you want to use guava-19 or guava-25 or maybe guava-23. This can only be found out by testing the application against different versions. Hopefully, you find one which suits both applications.

How to set the version: The easiest thing is to use `<dependencyManagement>`. Put the right version in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your POM and this will override all transitive definitions.

You could add a section like this (or integrate it into your existing `<dependencyManagement>` section):

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>26.0-jre</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: What should i put inside <dependencyManagement> ?